# Query that returns parent items with no children

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

It has products. Some are related to a parent product by a "Parent ID".

I need a query that will only select parent products that don't have any children related to it. Such as "Product-4".

Can anyone help me with this? It seems quite an easy solution.

Comment: Why not product 2 and 3 too?

Comment: @jarlh, they are not parent product

Comment: How do we know they aren't?

Comment: @jarlh, that's the whole point, I need to select products that don't have children. Right now, table has only 4 products. I need to return only products that don't have any other products that related to it. So if I delete products 2 & 3, then product 1 will be returned as well. But right now, it wont.

Comment: So you mean there can not be more than one level? No grandparents or grandchildren?

Comment: @maythesource.com, unfortunately I can't change the structure or the logic of my tables. I am using 0 as NULL and I must continue work with it. =\

Comment: @jarlh, that's right. There are no deeper relations than that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And why don't you use proper foreign keys in that table? The root should be stored with `parent_id = null` not some magic number.

Comment: Thank all of you! You guys really came to my help quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

1. Get Parent Product by checking `ParentId = 0`
2. Remove those `ParentId` who has children product

Here, Full Query,

```
Select * from Table_Name 
Where ParentId = 0
   AND Id NOT IN (Select DISTINCT ParentId from Table_Name WHERE ParentId NOT NULL)
```

Comment: No need for DISTINCT in the sub-query! What will happen if a ParentId  is null?

Comment: @jarlh, I remove those null entry by checking not null.

Comment: That's why I prefer `NOT EXISTS`, it's "null safe".

Comment: plus1 = This was the first correct answer so I am giving +1

Comment: Thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like: `SELECT * FROM parents WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE products.parent_id = parents.id) = 0` but not sure and can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I didn't realize this table had a relationship with itself.

The following should work:

```
 SELECT *
FROM   my_table m1
WHERE  NOT exists
       (
              SELECT *
              FROM   my_table m2
              WHERE  m1.id = m2.parent_id)
AND    parent_id = 0;
```

This should not select children.

Comment: It will give him Products-1 also

Comment: @Mahedi Sabuj So what exactly is the criteria to find children etc? Critical information is missing.

Comment: He want those product who are either parent or don't have any child. here, Product-1 has 2 childs (Product-2 & Product-3)

Comment: as Mahedi Sabuj said :)

Comment: You need to add ParentId = 0 to the where clause.

Comment: @ jarlh Your totally right... otherwise I selected the children as well (products 2 and 3).